# Changed color when load image in iOS app?

Tags: ios, photoshop

I have following images:

**Original PNG**

[image] [image]

**Load in iOS App**

[image] [image]

As seen, left side icon color works perfectly, but for right side icon, why iOS load different color? It applies on both iOS simulator and device. Is it wrong setting when saving the PNG in Photoshop?

And I don't have any code to change the color or tint.

Comment: Have you tried `imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal` ?

Answer (score 1):

It is not related to iOS code, since it also occured on Android.

The solution is, we need to use the actual bit depth. I use 8 bit depth (automatically by Photoshop) while actually the icon uses 16 bit depth when editing the icon.